# jQuery incorrect reference of 'this'

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $.getJSON("./data/journeys.json", (data) => {
        $.each(data, (i, journey) => {
            $("#journeyListings > tbody").append("<tr class='journeyOrder_" + journey.order + "'>" +
                                                     "<td>" + journey.originStation + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + journey.destinationStation + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + journey.startTime + "</td>" +
                                                     "<td>" + journey.arrivalTime + "</td>" +
                                                 "</tr>")
        });

        $("tr").on("click", () => {
            alert($(this).attr("class"));
        });
    });
});
```

On the 'click' method, I am trying to reference the row that has just been clicked (`tr`). When I refer to `$(this)`, it seems that I am referring to the ajax `getJson` method as I am getting `undefined` in my alert. How can I reference the element instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the ES6 arrow function, which changes the scoping of this, go back to the long function form:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Of course, if you want to stick with ES6, you should avoid `this` and use the event's `currentTarget` property:

```
$('tr').on('click', (e)=>{
   alert( $(e.currentTarget).attr('class') );
})
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you! Will accept when I can

Comment: just want to add the currentTarget, you was to quick hehe :)